Rollup summary shows (very) incorrect currency value
I have a classic Invoice__c object with InvoiceItem__c children.
I had for some (bad) reason one invoice with EUR as Currency, and one invoice item with CAD.
The Sub_Total__c of the item is -9750 (it's a credit note). It's a formula, classic unitprice x qty.
On the invoice I have a rollup summary, sum of items Sub_Total__c values.
So far so good, but after I've corrected the invoice item currency from -9750 CAD to -9750 EUR, the total shows -9929.05352997535.
I tried to clone the item to update the rollup, figuring that changing the currency only would not have triggered the rollup update, but it updated the total to 2 x -9929.05...
I also tried to change the price and the quantity but it still doesn't make the sum of a single value correctly !
I calculated that the ratio between the expected and the actual values is 1.01836, which looks like no conversion rate in the org. The rate between EUR and CAD is more around 1.50.
So I thougth maybe Salesforce would have kept the original conversion rate to calculate the summary, but it doesn't even seem to be the reason.
I don't know why or how to fix it.
Any ideas ?

just doing some more calculations I think there could be a double conversion . Once from EUR to CAD with the rate at the invoice creation date, and one from CAD to EUR with today's rate. one divided by th other seems to give something like 1.01836. (but I don't have the exact rate used then).

I deleted and restored the line, and that solve the issue. Weird though...
